# Eclipse Android - must clean with every build to compile latest code

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm building an Android app within Eclipse that uses a library.

However within the last day, I've had to clean the project every time I want to do a build to ensure the latest code is used.

Is there is setting i've accidentally triggered to do this, and how do I disable it so I dont have to do a clean every time!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling Build Automatically is not your answer. There is something you've changed.. maybe a call to your integrated library or something linking outside resources. Build Automatically will simply build your project after every save or change it sees in the workspace environments.

In Android development the generated resource files many times account for mistakes in Builds and the need to clean/build.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the option "Build automatically" is enabled. The option beneath "Clean Project".

Comment: Ok, it is enabled - should it not be?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because I noticed that my .apk does not update, and I worked around it using both eclipse and the command line.

- First clean the project, then try to Run as Android Application (it gives me an error and in the Console there is a suggestion to manually restart the Device)
- This failure creates a new .apk file in the bin folder.
- Now with the new .apk file go to the command line - go to the `platform-tools` folder of your android installation and use the command `adb install -r absolute/path/to/the/apkFile.apk`

It is tedious and if you omit the `-r` option it will fail if the program is already installed on the emulator.